# Maximum of parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $F(u,t)\in C^\infty(U\times[0,T])$ and $M$ is constant, if 
$$
\partial_tF\leq\Delta F-F^2+M^2 ~~~\forall (u,t)\in U\times[0,T]
$$
Then,could I have that $F$ reach maximum at the $\partial U\times[0,T]\bigcup U\times\{0,T\}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $F(x,t)=t(T-t)$, and $M\geq T^2+1$. This is a counter example.

Comment: 你好，，，，，，，，，，，，，，